# neo4j + mysql in spring data transactions not working

Tags: mysql, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to build an application using both MySQL and neo4j. 
Currently I succeed on saving an entity in both of the databases, but when I try to create a rollback only MySQL changes are rollbacked.
I'm not sure if the mode="proxy" configuration for the transactions can even work for neo4j, can someone approve/deny?
I'm using the @Transactional annotation over the relevant method, and I initiate a rollback by throwing a RuntimeException, which as I mentioned causes a rollback on MySQL.
My Configurations:

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" entityManagerFactory="entityManagerFactory"/>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data"/>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="...">
<neo4j:repositories base-package="..."/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="..."
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="..."/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Database -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/..."/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="transactionManagerMysql"/>
            <ref bean="transactionManagerNeo4j"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManagerMysql" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManagerNeo4j" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What happens if you use mode="aspectj" for transactions ?

Comment: It doesn't work at all because of missing configurations.
But I think that Spring Data's Rest access for neo4j doesn't support transactions.

Comment: I only used embedded mode but yes, it seems they don't support transactions for rest. You can extend the server with your operations and invoke it with rest. In this way you can have transactions. Although I think each cypher query over rest executes in a transaction.

Comment: If you want to do that, you'll have to go with an embedded instance, or create a Java server extension that uses SDN